# How to write multiple backups in one tape?

Tags: backup

I am using HP LTO -4 Tape and I want to make backup in tape drive without losing my old data of tape.

```
tar -czf /dev/st0 /www /home
```

When I run this command so every time my old data are removed and new backup is there.

But I want to keep my old and new backup.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because after performing a task /dev/st0 will rewind to begining of tape. So when you run `tar` to write a new backup the tape is overwritten from the beginning.

Before writing a new backup position the tape at end of the recorded media:

```
mt -f /dev/st0 eom
```

Then next backup will be written after previous one.

You can also use /dev/nst0. In this case the tape will not be rewind, so you can write one backup after another without searching for the end of media.

Before restoring a backup, position the tape at the one you want:

```
mt -f /dev/st0 rewind
mt -f /dev/st0 fsf <bkp # -1>
```

When you rewind the tape will be positioned at the first backup, so if you want to restore the third one run `mt -f /dev/st0 fsf 2` before `tar`.

Comment: If you set the TAPE environment variable to /dev/st0 or /dev/nst0, depending on your preferences, then you don't have to write it each time, neither in mt nor in tar.